# Reverse a list of string giving me none

Tags: python, python-3.x

s is a string and following code is giving me "None" while executing

```
n=list(s)
l = n.reverse()
print(l)
```

Comment: there is no problem with your code check if your string 's' is None

Comment: the reversed string is stored in n.

Comment: It's conventional in Python for functions & methods which mutate their argument in-place to return `None`.

Comment: Here we can do the same as you could read in my previous comments. You need to edit your this question to make it **very clear** that it is not a duplicate, **but without making the already posted answers invalid**. I am not sure if it can be done, but if yes, do the same (edit it, click "reopen", ping me in a comment and I cast another reopen vote).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## reverse

You got to copy the list and then reverse it with l.reverse(), not l = n.reverse().

## copy

You have to use copy, not just l = n, because if you do so you will have two reference to the same data, so that when you reverse l you reverse also n. If you do not want to reverse also the original n list, you have to make a brand new copy with l = n. copy, then you reverse l, without modifying the original data stored with n label. You can copy a list also with l = n[:].

```
>>> s = "12345"
>>> n = list(s)
>>> l = n.copy() # or l = n[:]
>>> l.reverse()
>>> n
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
>>> l
['5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
>>>
```

## Thake a list and get the items in a string

If you want a string back

```
>>> k = "".join(l)
>>> k
'54321'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
n=list(s)
n.reverse()
print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [::-1] for reverse.Slice notation is easy to reverse string

```
s = "reverse"
s  = s[::-1]
print(s)
```

**output**

```
esrever
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem:
`reverse()` function is doing in place reversal of list and it is not returning anything that's the reason `l` gets assigned `None`

As a solution after calling `reverse()` print variable `n` itself as shown

```
s = "abc"
n=list(s)
n.reverse()
print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your code, it should be

```
s='string'
n=list(s)
n.reverse()
print(''.join(n))
```

Output:

```
gnirts
```

Answer (score -1):

reverse() function returns None but reverse the list.

```
n=list(s)
l = n.reverse()
print(l)
print(n) #Reversed list
```

Comment: You've just restated the problem, not offered explanation or solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `reversed()` function as well.

```
l = list(reversed(n))
print(l)
```

Comment: `reversed` returns a reverse iterator, it doesn't make a new reversed `list` unless you `list`ify it. Try your code before posting!

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for the help